# Poorly performing query needs assistance

Tags: mysql

I have the below query which works fine, but is very slow and doesn't return the results fast enough for my needs.

It shows the 9 most commonly picked players across the 11 positions.

Does anyone see a better way of writing it?

```
select PlayerName, RankName, Position
from
(
select Opener1 as Player from Team
where CompetitionIDAuto = 1
union all
select Opener2 as Player from Team
where CompetitionIDAuto = 1
union all
select Bat1 as Player from Team
where CompetitionIDAuto = 1 
union all
select Bat2 as Player from Team
where CompetitionIDAuto = 1 
union all
select Bat3 as Player from Team
where CompetitionIDAuto = 1 
union all
select WK as Player from Team
where CompetitionIDAuto = 1 
union all
select AR1 as Player from Team
where CompetitionIDAuto = 1 
union all
select Bowl1 as Player from Team
where CompetitionIDAuto = 1 
union all
select Bowl2 as Player from Team
where CompetitionIDAuto = 1  
union all
select Bowl3 as Player from Team
where CompetitionIDAuto = 1 
union all
select Bowl4 as Player from Team
where CompetitionIDAuto = 1 
) a
Inner Join Player on a.Player = Player.PlayerIDAuto
Inner Join RankValue on Player.ODIRank = RankValue.RankIDAuto
Inner Join PlayerPosition on Player.ODIPosition = PlayerPosition.PlayerPositionIDAuto
group by PlayerName
order by count(*) desc
Limit 0,9
```

Comment: I would recommend normalizing your data.  Instead of having a single table with a field for each position, have a table that has team, position and player for fields.  This would be much more efficient for querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, the best strategy would be to split your main source table into two, so that, instead of:

```
PlayerID_role1 PlayerID_role2 PlayerID_role3 ... CompetitionIDAuto
```

one table (Team) would look like:

```
PlayerID RoleID CompetitionID
```

plus one more separate table (e.g. Competition) to autonumerate competitions, which would include all other competition information, e.g.

```
CompetitionIDAuto CompetitionName CompetitionDate...
```

Then you could do a query like:

```
select PlayerName, RankName, Position from Team where CompetitionIdAuto = 1
Inner Join Player on Team.PlayerID = Player.PlayerIDAuto
Inner Join RankValue on Player.ODIRank = RankValue.RankIDAuto
Inner Join PlayerPosition on Player.ODIPosition = PlayerPosition.PlayerPositionIDAuto
group by Player.PlayerIDAuto
order by count(*) desc
Limit 0,9
```

Note: don't group by PlayerName, because PlayerIDAuto is (I guess) an autoincrementing primary index field, whereas PlayerName is, most probably, not an index at all. Grouping by non-indexed field is slow by definition. (You can do this improvement for the query on your current table as well).

Comment: Thanks, seems the most sensible. Glad to hear I wasn't missing anything obvious with my original query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try maybe:

```
select PlayerName, RankName, Position
from
(
    select CONCAT('|', Opener1, '|', Opener2, '|', Bat1, '|', Bat2, '|', Bat3, '|', WK, '|', AR1, '|', Bowl1, '|', Bowl2, '|', Bowl3, '|', Bowl4, '|') as Player from Team
    where CompetitionIDAuto = 1 
) a
Inner Join Player on LOCATE(CONCAT('|', Player.PlayerIDAuto, '|'), a.Player) <> 0
Inner Join RankValue on Player.ODIRank = RankValue.RankIDAuto
Inner Join PlayerPosition on Player.ODIPosition = PlayerPosition.PlayerPositionIDAuto
group by PlayerName
order by count(*) desc
Limit 0,9
```

As for normalization of your table (if that's possible) I think that @Tom is right.

Comment: Thanks, same result as my query really.

Comment: No problem - with the structure given nothing else came to my mind.